# How to express one linear regression variable as a sum of others with confidence interval?

Tags: r, multiple-regression

I have a clustered linear regression with the dataframe: mixed effects.
Brier is a numerical variable, TimeToSettlement is a numerical variable, Boost is a dummy variable (0 or 1) and QuestionID is categorical.

```
testlmer <- lmerTest::lmer(Brier ~ TimeToSettlement + Boost + (1|QuestionID), data = mixedeffects)
```

`summary(testlmer)`

This gives me the following output:
[image: Code output]

Essentially I would like to express Boost in terms of TimeToSettlement.
To do this I can just rearrange the equation:

Brier = 0.01321 + 0.003023*TimeToSettlement - 0.02574*Boost.

Given this I can instead express the equation as:

Brier = 0.01321 + 0.003023*(TimeToSettlement - (0.02574/0.003023)*Boost)

So a difference of 1 in Boost is equivalent to a difference of -0.02574/0.003023 = ~ -8 in TimeToSettlement. Is there any standard way to get a confidence interval around this number (as we can using 1.96*standard error for the initial coefficient for 'Boost')?